# How put put data labels inside bar in VizFrame Chart

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to make a bar chart with VizFrame. Right now this is what my chart looks like:

[image: My Chart]

**edit Chart wont embed? Here is the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZmaD.jpg

How would I go about putting the data label inside the bar if it can fit? I tried looking it up, but I am having trouble solving this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to display the data labels inside the bars use the `plotArea.dataLabel.position` property. As stated in the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/vizdocs/index.html#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Bar%20%20(15)/Bar%20Chart/) the property has the following features:

- Supported Value Type: String
- Supported Values: inside, outside, outsideFirst
- Readonly: false
- Serializable: true
- Default value: "outsideFirst"
- Description: Set data label display
  position. 'outsideFirst' means if the plot has no space to display data
  label outside of the bar, the data label will be displayed inside.

one option to set the property would be for example in the `onInit` method of the `controller` of the `view`:

```
...
onInit: function() {
  oVizFrameBar = this.byId("idVizFrameBar"); 
  oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
    plotArea: {
      dataLabel: {
        position: 'inside'
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```